# Display complex numbers in UI when using wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, wxpython

I know complex math and the necessary operations (either "native" Python, or through NumPy). My question has to do with how to display complex numbers in a UI using wxPython. All the questions I found dealing with Python and complex numbers have to do with manipulating complex data.

My original thought was to subclass wx.TextCtrl and override the set and get methods to apply and strip some formatting as needed, and concatenating an i (or j) to the imaginary part.

Am I going down the wrong path? I feel like displaying complex numbers is something that should already be done somewhere.

What would be the recommended pattern for this even when using another UI toolkit, as the problem is similar. Also read my comment below on why I would like to do this.

Comment: In any UI you display strings and you read strings from the user. Why would you mix the type to string or string to type translation with widgets functionality? Get them, convert and use,  or "print" them to string and show the string in the ui.

Comment: `str(<somenativecomplex>)` already gives you a string for you to adjust.

Comment: @progmatico Well, wxPython has wx.SpinCtrlDouble which has built in validation for numbers, incrementing, decrementing, etc. I would like a control with similar behavior but for complex numbers. I come from programming in LabVIEW which is trivial to output a complex array to a UI control (for example). If my approach should be modified, then I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Ok I see, if you really want a custom widget for something then yes subclassing an existing control is the way to go, if you can't find one and want to reuse the widget.

Comment: Although this could be opinion based I don't see why you don't get any answers. I am not using wxpython but the question is valid in any UI framework. I am editing the tags maybe your question wasn't seen by enough people.

Comment: The main reason I'm focused on this is that I don't want to build an entire UI, only to later find I need to restructure it to do what I want to with complex numbers. I'm very much in the learning phase right now. Your suggestion of formatting and parsing for a wx.TextCtrl, along with using a validator seems like a way to move forward (if I've interpreted your early comments correctly). Once I learn them, it appears I can attach a wx.Validator to the controls to ensure complex data, or coerce non-compliant complex data.

Comment: That's what I meant indeed. In the end if you like what you did I think that wrapping the functionality in a TextCtrl subclass for reuse will be trivial.

Comment: If you need to do equations, wxPython has support for embedding matplotlib in it. There's a neat recipe here - https://wiki.wxpython.org/MatplotlibEquationEditor

Comment: @progmatico, feel free to post your first comment as an answer. I'm not working on that project anymore, but it told me what I should do.

Comment: I am glad it helped, Brian.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian considered my first comment good advice, and he got no more answers, I am posting it as an answer. Please refer also to the other question comments discussing the issue.

> In any UI you display strings and you read strings from the user. Why
>   would you mix the type to string or string to type translation with
>   widgets functionality? Get them, convert and use, or "print" them to
>   string and show the string in the ui.